# Creating a Report with Multiple Paramters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

If have a SQL Server Table with 3 columns

```
ID    int,
Date  Date,
Name   varchar(max)
```

My question is

Assuming that I created 3 Parameters `@ID , @Date , @Name`
If want to make a report for this table where it returns to me Data based on which parameter was Provided , so can it be done in one report ? or am I going to have to create 3 reports for the 3 parameters , Each report Filters the data with its own parameter ?

If its possible to be done in one report , please provide me with any links to check.

Comment: Hmm? You're question is a bit unclear? Have you *tried* creating a report with three parameters yet? You can just use all of them in your dataset queries, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: @Jeroen No the report that I want to create doesn't require the three parameters to be given , I mean I only need the data to populated with only one parameter given , so if I gave a value to the [ID Parameter] the report automatically filters data by the ID Column , if I gave a value to the [Name Parameter] the report filters data by the Name column and the same goes for the third parameter

Comment: Create one report with 3 parameters, and make sure each parameter has an "ALL" option, which means to NOT filter by that parameter at all.   You have to handle that in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a report with multiple parameters. Hope this links help.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385719(v=sql.110).aspx

And yes its possible to be in one or more reports. I have tried using multiple parameters on my reports. 
You can also watch  tutorials on youtube